# Using TServerSocket (Non-Block I/O) inside a child thread (TThread)

Tags: delphi, sockets

I'm creating an instance of `TServerSocket` inside a class that is inherited from `TThread`. My question is, what code should be inside the `Execute` procedure which is the MAIN thread code ?

```
TServerThread = class(TThread)
private
  FServerSocket: TServerSocket;

  // FServerSocket event handlers
  procedure ClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  procedure ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  procedure ClientError(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer);
  procedure ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
  procedure Listen(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
protected
  procedure Execute; override;
public
  constructor Create;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;
```

that's how the the class looks like, so you'll get the idea of how its implementation would look like.

the reason i'm asking this, is because all of the main code is happening in the event handlers, i can't think of any busy work operation that the MAIN procedure (Execute) should do, except loop and sleep ?

in [here](http://www.delphigroups.info/2/12/487883.html), someone suggested a message loop, but i don't think the thread will recv any messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TServerSocket` in non-blocking mode uses a hidden window to process window messages for socket activity, so the thread's `Execute()` method needs to have an active message loop to dispatch those messages, eg:

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  ...
  ServerSocket.Active := True;
  try
    while not Terminated do
    begin
      if GetMessage(Msg, 0, 0, 0) > 0 then
      begin
        TranslateMessage(Msg);
        DispatchMessage(Msg);
      end else begin
        Break;
      end;
      ...
    end;
  finally
    ServerSocket.Active := False;
  end;
  ...
end;

procedure TMyThread.Stop;
begin
  PostThreadMessage(ThreadID, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);
end;
```

Comment: **Q1**: _Does Embarcadero have a documentation on the hidden window that would explain it better to me_ ?

**Q2**: _If i understood you correctly, i do not need to start the TServerSocket explicity from the constructor, it will start inside the Execute procedure_ ?

**Q3**: _Lets say i drop a TServerSocket to the Main Form, and assign it to the child thread inside the constructor, does the MAIN THREAD (Vlc Thread) handles those hidden window messages_ ?

Comment: **Q1:** No. **Q2:** you must activate the server inside of `Execute()`. If you activate it in the constructor instead, the hidden window will get associated with the thread context that creates your worker thread (presumably the main thread), thus `Execute()` will not receive any of the socket's window messages. **Q3:** Whichever thread context activates the server will be the thread context that receives the socket messages.

Comment: Out of curiosity though... how do you know about this hidden window ?

Comment: Looking at the VCL's source code for `TClientSocket` and `TServerSocket` in ScktComp.pas.

Comment: The hidden window is created by `AllocateHWnd()` inside of `TCustomWinSocket.GetHandle()`. The `TCustomWinSocket.Handle` property is used by `TCustomWinSocket.AsyncInitSocket()`, `TCustomWinSocket.DoSetAsyncStyles()`, and `TCustomWinSocket.DeferFree()` for non-blocking sockets. `TCustomWinSocket.DoSetAsyncStyles()` calls the Winsock `WSAAsyncSelect()` function to register the window to receive socket events.

Comment: Another question (sorry ;]), what messages does the TServerSocket instance receives and from whom ?

Comment: @user1803300: Please study ScktComp.pas, all of the answers are in it. You don't need to deal with the window messages directly yourself, you just need to provide your thread with a message loop so the messages can be dispatched to `TServerSocket`, but only if you use it in non-blocking mode to begin with.